# Converting large number of seconds to `H:i:s` format

Tags: php, mysql

In the image below,

**`SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(talktime)))`** value is on right and

**`SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(talktime))`** is on left.

[image]

Last value given by `SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(talktime)))` is `838:59:59`

I tried this **`echo gmdate("H:i:s", 4874010);`**.but this also has limit 86,400.

Can you please help me in converting large number of seconds to `H:i:s` format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an overflow on the `time` type.  I think the MySQL [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/time.html) is pretty clear on the limits:

> MySQL retrieves and displays `TIME` values in 'HH:MM:SS' format (or
>   'HHH:MM:SS' format for large hours values). `TIME` values may range from
>   '-838:59:59' to '838:59:59'.

EDIT:

You can convert the seconds to time manually:

```
select concat_ws(':',
                 floor(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(talktime)) / 3600),
                 lpad(mod(floor(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(talktime) / 60)), 60), 2, '0'),
                 lpad(mod(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(talktime)), 60), 2, '0')
                )
```

Answer (score 1):

In PHP you can use the built in DateTime class for this type of operation.

Example:

```
$seconds = 4874010;
echo DateTime::createFromFormat("!d","1")->diff(new DateTime("@$seconds"))->format("%a days, %h hours, %m minutes, %s seconds");
```

Output:

> 56 days, 4 hours, 1 minutes, 30 seconds

[PHP: DateTime - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)